# Public SOAP Web Services

Tags: web-services, soap

I need some public Web Services to list and analyse them. The services should not be secured by password or some key.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are some, as you requested:

- http://www.gcomputer.net/webservices/dilbert.asmx
- http://www.xml-webservices.net/services/conversions/euro_convert/euro_conver.asmx
- https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso
- https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/TextCasing.wso

Comment: The 4th and 5th links are not more available.

Comment: This webservice works too: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

Comment: The third is not working anymore

Comment: only Dilbert service is working.

Comment: Dilbert service doesn't seem to work anymore, it fails SSL/TLS authentication, site doesn't have a valid security certificate.

Comment: This is a collection of different SOAP APIs that are completley public and do not require any authentication, making it easier for consumers to play with and understand what APIs are all about by seeing the many different ways in which APIs can be used.

 [Public SOAP APIs - Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/Szf26WHn#4ba276a7-b12c-4943-ae23-c6031cc48248)
Remember, you can get a WSDL from any ASMX endpoint by adding `?wsdl` to the url.